# Target label in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, target

Is there a possible way to target the label for an input in css3? For example I tried this method -

```
input[type="text"]:focus label:target {
    color:orange !important;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work, just wondering or is this a job for jquery only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`:target` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo) doesn't do what you think it does, and `label` can never exist as a descendant of `input`, so that won't work.

If you're trying to refer to a `label` which is associated with an `input` either by parentage or the `for` attribute, that's not possible with CSS3. You can only refer to the `label` if it's a sibling that follows the `input`, with either one of these:

```
input[type="text"]:focus + label
input[type="text"]:focus ~ label
```

If the `label` is an ancestor, preceding sibling or completely elsewhere, you'll need to use jQuery to traverse the DOM and locate it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by it being a sibling?

Comment: @Matt: Something like `<input type="text" id="i"><label for="i">Label directly following its input</label>` where you have a label tag just after an input tag, without one containing the other.

Comment: hmm I tried that and still didn't seem to work...here is a portion of the form and the css -> http://pastebin.com/gdHY0xeH

Comment: @Matt: Oh, sorry - I left the `:target` selector in there; it shouldn't be used at all.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS4 you can do this:

```
!label /for/ input[type="text"]:focus,
!label input[type="text"]:focus {
    ...
}
```

The first one allows for `<label for="inputid">`, and the second for `<label><input type="text"/></label>`

However CSS4 support is extremely limited. Still, there's no harm in putting it there.

Comment: `s/CSS4/Selectors 4/` Also, the reference combinator goes from `[idref]` to `[id]`, but not the other way around, so you would instead write `!label /for/ input[type="text"]:focus`.

Comment: but I'm pretty sure only one browser supports CSS4..if that :P half the browsers don't even support all of CSS3 yet.

Comment: See, this is the problem with saying "CSS4". There is no such thing as CSS4, and it's not possible for any browser to *ever* support *all* of CSS3 because it is always growing, and it doesn't only represent "all level 3 modules", instead it means any part of CSS that extends from CSS2. But, you know, everything comes at a cost, and this is the cost of abruptly changing from a global leveling system (CSS1,2) to a modular system (> CSS2).